About $1^{\rm st}$ order phase transitions in Landau theory
Suppose that we have a magnetic system described by the following free energy ($\eta$ being the order parameter, in this case the magnetization)
$$\mathcal{L}(\eta,t,h)=at\eta^{2}-w\eta^{3}+\frac{b}{4}\eta^{4}-h\eta\hspace{1cm}a,b>0$$
where $t=\frac{T-T^{*}}{T^{*}}$ is the difference between the temperatures $T, T^{*}$, and $T^{\ast}$ denotes the temperature at which a phase transition occurs if one sets $w=0$.
However, for $w\neq 0$ it happens that there is another value of the temperature (say $T=T_{t}$) for which the equilibrium state changes from $\eta_{0}=0$ to $\eta_{+}\neq 0$. It is written (at least in my notes) that this corresponds to a first order transition. Why is this the case? Is it simply because
$$\lim_{T\rightarrow T_{t}}\frac{∂\mathcal{L}}{∂T}=a\eta_{0}^{2}\neq a\eta_{+}^{2}=\lim_{T\rightarrow T_{t}}\frac{∂\mathcal{L}}{∂T}$$
or are there other reasons?

Essentially yes. Alternatively you could consider $\lim_{T\rightarrow T_i} -\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial h} = \lim_{T\rightarrow T_i} \eta$ which obviously is also a discontinuous first derivative

Please write it as an answer so I can accept it:)
